# NServiceBus: Access to recoverability in feature

Tags: nservicebus

Using NServiceBus v7.4.6 plus .NET Core 3.1 and getting the exception

*The given key NServiceBus.RecoverabilitySettings was not present in the dictionary.*

with the code below when trying to get `RecoverabilitySettings` in the feature. What could be wrong?

```cs
public class MyFeature : Feature
{
    protected override void Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context)
    {
        var recoverability = context.Settings.Get<RecoverabilitySettings>();
        recoverability.Failed(settings => settings.OnMessageSentToErrorQueue(message =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.MessageId);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }));
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var host = Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseConsoleLifetime()
            .UseNServiceBus(c =>
            {
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("MyEndpoint");
                
                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBusTransport");
                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
                transport.ConnectionString(connectionString);
                endpointConfiguration.EnableFeature<MyFeature>();
                
                return endpointConfiguration;
            })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

### Update

I try to [update the feature](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/7to8/#error-notification-events) from older version 7 of NServiceBus to the latest one where `ErrorsNotifications.MessageSentToErrorQueue` become obsolete. The old feature code was like

```cs
public class MyOldFeature : Feature
{
    protected override void Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context)
    {
        var notifications = context.Settings.Get<Notifications>();
        notifications.Errors.MessageSentToErrorQueue += this.OnMessageSentToErrorQueue;
    }

    private void OnMessageSentToErrorQueue(object sender, FailedMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.MessageId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/7to8/#error-notification-events

> In NServiceBus version 7.2, error notification events for MessageSentToErrorQueue, MessageHasFailedAnImmediateRetryAttempt, and MessageHasBeenSentToDelayedRetries using .NET events were deprecated in favor of Task-based callbacks. In NServiceBus version 8 and above, the event-based notifications will throw an error.
>
> Error notifications can be set with the Task-based callbacks through the recoverability settings:

Settings API is not type-safe and behavior can change across major versions which prevents usage Obsolete in this case on `RecoverabilitySettings` as that type is still used.

I've created the following issue as I think we could do better in the feedback on this specific breaking change:

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/6080